# How to extract useful information from a string with PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

I'm using a string that is composed the following way:

```
0003customer-23892644362977289 28 23892644362977293 29 23892644362977294 30
```

First four characters: The number of registries to be processed.

String "customer-": Defines the table to be used

The next part of the chain is defined as a key => value for a string (uuid_short => remote id)

I need to separate each part of the chain so it can be processed locally.
I tried using substrings, explode and the following loop:

```
$array = explode(" ", $string);

for($i = 0, $b = 0; $b < $num_of_registries; $i = $i + 2, $b++)
{
  $local = $array[$i];
  $remote = $array[$i+1];
  // store values in array

  $inserted = array();
  $inserted['local'] = $local; 
  $inserted['remote'] = $remote;
  $array_inserted[] = $inserted;
}

foreach ($array_inserted as $key => $value)
{
  echo $value["local"].' => '.$value["remote"].' <p>';
}
```

But the loop only works with single character value pairs.

Comment: provide the expected output.

Comment: Is `-` being used as a delimiter in the table name?

Comment: I need to extract the first four character in order to define the length of the loop, i need the table name to know upon which table to act, the - after the table is used as a delimiter, after that I would need to extract each value pair in order to insert them into an array

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the entire process I was using. I can also update the string structure if needed.

Comment: Split on the delimiter, use your current substring logic to get the number of registries from `split[0]`, then split on space on `split[1]` and modify your current for loop to use that last split instead of `$array`.

Comment: @vicman i didn't find any expected output in the edit you made.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I would need the First four characters into a variable, the characters before the - into a variable as well, the rest of the chain as a key => value into an array

Comment: Is the rest always going to be space delimited?  If so do you need to even use the first four characters to determine the # of key->value pairs to follow (assuming all records are complete)?

Comment: Since I am getting the response from a server I do need to know the number of records to be entered. But I take that part of the string out using substr, what I really need to work on is on the value pair combination.

Comment: Now I've noticed.... Why the `regex` tag if you don't even say it once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voila.

```
if (preg_match("#^([0-9]+)(.*?)-(.*)#", $string, $out)) {
    echo "number: ".$out[1]."\n";
    echo "table: ".$out[2]."\n";
    if (preg_match_all("#([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)#", $out[3], $res, PREG_SET_ORDER))
       foreach ($res as $r) echo "$r[1] => $r[2]\n";
}
```

Result

```
number: 0003
table: customer
23892644362977289 => 28
23892644362977293 => 29
23892644362977294 => 30
```

Comment: How would you handle `0001customer-23892644362977289 28 23892644362977293 29 23892644362977294 30`?

Comment: The first part of the regular expression handles all numbers (preg_match("#^([0-9]+)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the lack of a representation, this is merely speculative.

This is what I came up with:

```
<?

$string='0003customer-23892644362977289 28 23892644362977293 29 23892644362977294 30';

$array = explode('-', $string);

$header = current( $array );

$times = (int)$header;

$data = array();

$data[$key = substr($header, 4)] = explode(' ', $array[1]);

print_r($data);
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [customer] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23892644362977289
            [1] => 28
            [2] => 23892644362977293
            [3] => 29
            [4] => 23892644362977294
            [5] => 30
        )

)
```

If you want `key=>value`, you may want this:

```
$string='0003customer-23892644362977289 28 23892644362977293 29 23892644362977294 30';

$array = explode('-', $string);

$header = current( $array );

$times = (int)$header;
$key = substr($header, 4);

$data = array("$key"=>array());

$content = explode(' ', $array[1]);

for($i=0;$i < $times * 2;)
{
    $data[$key][$content[$i++]]=$content[$i++];
}

print_r($data);
```

Which prints:

```
Array
(
    [customer] => Array
        (
            [23892644362977289] => 28
            [23892644362977293] => 29
            [23892644362977294] => 30
        )

)
```

Or this:

```
$string='0003customer-23892644362977289 28 23892644362977293 29 23892644362977294 30';

$array = explode('-', $string);

$header = current( $array );

$times = (int)$header;
$key = substr($header, 4);

$data = array("$key"=>array());

$content = explode(' ', $array[1]);

for($i=0;$i < $times * 2;)
{
    $data[$key][$content[1+$i++]]=$content[$i++-1];
}

print_r($data);
```

Which prints:

```
Array
(
    [customer] => Array
        (
            [28] => 23892644362977289
            [29] => 23892644362977293
            [30] => 23892644362977294
        )

)
```

---

**Edit:**

Removed the `$times * 2` on every `explode()`, in case the input comes as `0001customer-23892644362977289 28 23892644362977293 29 23892644362977294 30` (notice the `0001`).

Comment: @vicman You're welcome. If you need that I explain the code, and which bit you are interested in, just ask and I will gladly answer.

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible through a single regex.

```
(?:^(.{4})([^-]*)|\G)[\s-](\S+)\s+(\S+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bP0xU1/4)

```
$str = "0003customer-23892644362977289 28 23892644362977293 29 23892644362977294 30";
preg_match_all('~(?:^(.{4})([^-]*)|\G)[\s-](\S+)\s+(\S+)~', $str, $matches);
echo "Number : ".$matches[1][0]."\n";
echo "Table : ".$matches[2][0]."\n";
print_r($matches[3]);
print_r($matches[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suck at regex, so I like to write regular PHP code so I know what's going on. Here you go:

```
$input = "0003customer-23892644362977289 28 23892644362977293 29 23892644362977294 30";

$resistry_count = substr($input, 0, 4);  // example: '0003'
$table = substr($input, 4, strpos($input, '-') - 4); // example: 'customer'
$data = substr($input, strpos($input, '-') + 1); // example: '23892644362977289 28 23892644362977293 29 23892644362977294 30'

$exploded = explode(" ", $data);
$chunked = array_chunk($exploded, 2);

$array = [];
foreach ($chunked as $row) {
    $array[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}
```

and your result should be:

```
Array
(
    [23892644362977289] => 28
    [23892644362977293] => 29
    [23892644362977294] => 30
)
```